# Spring Webflux - How to aggregate three Flux objects into 1 using Tuple3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tuples, spring-webflux

I am trying to aggregate 3 `Flux` objects into 1 using `Tuple3`
However, I am still stuck. I searched online and saw that you can use `Mono.zip()` but that doesn't apply to `Flux`.

```
public class OrderService {

    private final AppWebClient appWebClient;

    public Mono<OrderDetailsAggregate> getAggregatedOrderDetails(List<String> orderNoList1,
            List<String> orderNoList2, List<String> orderNoList3) {
        Flux<Map<String, List<String>>> fluxOne = this.appWebClient.getFluxOne(orderNoList1);
        Flux<Map<String, String>> fluxTwo = this.appWebClient.getFluxTwo(orderNoList2);
        Flux<Map<String, List<String>>> fluxThree = this.appWebClient.getFluxThree(orderNoList3);

        return Mono.zip(fluxOne, fluxTwo, fluxThree).map(this::combine); //error here
    }

    private OrderDetailsAggregate combine(
            Tuple3< Flux<Map<String, List<String>>>, Flux<Map<String, String>>, Flux<Map<String, List<String>>> > tuple) {
        return OrderDetailsAggregate.create(tuple.getT1(), tuple.getT2(), tuple.getT3()); 
    }

}
```

`fluxOne`, `fluxTwo`, `fluxThree` have different data types.

**OrderDetailsAggregate** class

```
@Data
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor(staticName = "create")
public class OrderDetailsAggregate {

    private Flux<Map<String, List<String>>>  fluxOne;
    private Flux<Map<String, String>> fluxTwo;
    private Flux<Map<String, List<String>>> fluxThree;
}
```

How do I combine them?

Thank you.

Comment: [Tuples.of(fluxOne, fluxTwo, fluxThree)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/util/function/Tuples.html#of-T1-T2-T3-) ? I am not sure, do you just want to pack fluxes together ? (i.e. Tuple3 factory above), or do you want to zip Flux contents, producing a single Flux combining each flux signal ? (in which case Flux.zip exists)

Comment: Thanks for your message @amanin. I am trying to zip the Flux contents to 1 object `OrderDetailsAggregate` to get aggregated contents as response
Example:
`{
    "fluxOne": {
        "123": ["ITEM1", "ITEM2", "ITEM3"]
    },
    "fluxTwo": {
        "456": "SomeValue"
    },
    "fluxThree": {
        "789": ["ITEM1", "ITEM2", "ITEM3"]
        "101": ["ITEM4", "ITEM5", "ITEM6"]
    }
`}

Comment: please do not post code in comments, as you can see its completely unreadaable, use the edit button on your question. And the answer is if you are using `Flux` why arn't you just using `Flux.zip`?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to return `Mono<OrderDetailsAggregate>` from `getAggregatedOrderDetails` method, then why  not just create `Mono` object without zip:

```java
public Mono<OrderDetailsAggregate> getAggregatedOrderDetails(List<String> orderNoList1,
                                                                 List<String> orderNoList2, List<String> orderNoList3) {
        Flux<Map<String, List<String>>> fluxOne = this.appWebClient.getFluxOne(orderNoList1);
        Flux<Map<String, String>> fluxTwo = this.appWebClient.getFluxTwo(orderNoList2);
        Flux<Map<String, List<String>>> fluxThree = this.appWebClient.getFluxThree(orderNoList3);
        OrderDetailsAggregate aggregate = OrderDetailsAggregate.create(fluxOne, fluxTwo, fluxThree);
        return Mono.just(aggregate);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like you are treating the Flux'es your `appWebClient` is returning as if they were Mono's.

I assume, you want to have all values of the fluxes in your `OrderDetailsAggregate`. Should that be the case, I would suggest to `collect` the Flux into a Mono, do a `Mono.zip` to get a tuple and map that to your `OrderDetailsAggregate`:

```java
public Mono<OrderDetailsAggregate> getAggregatedOrderDetails(List<String> orderNoList1,
            List<String> orderNoList2, List<String> orderNoList3) {
        Mono<Map<String, List<String>>> monoOne = this.appWebClient.getFluxOne(orderNoList1).collect(HashMap::new, Map::putAll);
        Mono<Map<String, String>> monoTwo = this.appWebClient.getFluxTwo(orderNoList2).collect(HashMap::new, Map::putAll);
        Mono<Map<String, List<String>>> monoThree = this.appWebClient.getFluxThree(orderNoList3).collect(HashMap::new, Map::putAll);

        return Mono.zip(monoOne, monoTwo, monoThree).map(tuple -> OrderDetailsAggregate.create(tuple.getT1(), tuple.getT2(), tuple.getT3()));
}
```

Should you just care about one value from the flux, then you can replace the `collect()` with `next()`.

Edit: I see you are passing `Flux` to your `create()` method. So this answer only applies if you would change that as well. If your `OrderDetailsAggregate` is a Dto and not a service, then it would perhaps be a good idea to not have that flux logic in there but rather do it in the `getAggregatedOrderDetails` method.